# ADC conversion error in code ATMEGA328p

Tags: c, atmega, atmel, adc, atmelstudio

I am trying to read values from ADC0 on the ATMEGA328p. The values expected are between 0-5v. This is due to ADC0 being connected to a potentiometer connected to the 5v output of a Xplained mini. I am getting either  0v or 5v usually. With no variation when the potentiometer is changed. I have looked at multiple ADC examples and tutorials online but cant find the error in my code.

```
void adc_initialise (){
    //set vref to AVcc, channel selection is initially ADC0 as wanted
    ADMUX |= (1<<6);
    //set ADC enable, Set adc clock prescalar 64
    ADCSRA |= (1<<7)|(1<<2)|(1<<1);
}

uint16_t adc_read (){
    ADCSRA |= (1<<6); // start conversion
    while( ADCSRA & (1<<ADSC) ); //wait until conversion is complete
    return ADCW;
}

float adc_calculation(uint16_t adcValue){
    float stepSize = (5.0/1024.0);
    float voltageIn = adcValue*stepSize;
    return voltageIn;   
}
```

then in my main i have

```
while(1){   
    adc_initialise();
    uint16_t adcValue = adc_read();
    float voltageIn = adc_calculation(adcValue);
    adcConverterToUART(voltageIn);//I know that this part of the code is working as I have hardcoded many test values and all have transmitted correctly.
}
```

And as mentioned above I know the error is not in my UART code but somewhere in the above ADC code. Cheers in advance for any help.

Comment: Store the integer value somewhere, and inspect the memory, and/or place a breakpoint there. Also, of course verify with a multimeter that you really do have a varying voltage at the point the ADC is connected. Electronics is hard. :)

Answer (score 0):

I could mention a few things. You could try it if it help.

1. You should do your `adc_initialise()` before the `while(1)`. 
   You initialize it again and again.
2. `while( ADCSRA & (1<<ADSC) );` here you should add maybe NOPs that the   compiler don't optimize it out of the code.

The rest looks good in my eyes.

Do you get any value of the conversion ?

mfg

EDIT1:

I looked in one of my old files. 
There we made it like this to get the value from the ADC.

```
  // Get count value
  adValue  = ADCL;
  adValue |= (UI_16_t)(ADCH << 8);
```

ADCL is the low byte of the value and ADCH the high byte.
We shifted the high byte in the front of the low byte to get the value.

Comment: yes my voltatgeIn that I transmit always seems to be flat 0v or 4.99v with no change when the potentiometer is changed

Comment: also does it matter if I have adc_initialise inside the while? I understand why it should be outside but originally I had a slightly different code and thought i may aswell put it in the while loop

Comment: @AmatuerCoder101 I "matters" at least in the sense that it fails to make sense. :) It's unexpected, strange, and can act as a kind of "alarm" to whoever reads your code that it was written by someone who was at least a little bit confused. Usually the entire point of initializing something is so that you can then go on an use it, the existance of an init function implies that there are operations that only need to be done once.

Comment: Ok so i moved my initiate outside the while loop and checked my testing and my test code on matlab only seems to plot the value at ADC0 when the script is started so my ADC is working but not my testing code.